# How can I redirect to my youtube subscription page in Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I don't want to see distracting youtube recommendations on my start screen, I just want to be redirected to my subscription page whenever I go to the `/` path of youtube.
I tried to redesign the youtube page in my DOM by using javascript to redirect from the `/` path to the `/feed/subscriptions` path automatically.

I created the following script, which unfortunately only works on page reload.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        YT redir /home -> /sub
// @match       https://www.youtube.com/*
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// @version     1.0
// @author      -
// @description 5/30/2020, 12:16:13 PM
// ==/UserScript==

var current_location = location.pathname;
if(current_location == "/"){
     window.location.replace("https://youtube.com/feed/subscriptions")
}
```

I expected this script to also work when I browse youtube and click on the home or youtube logo button. However it only works on page reload.

**How can I make this script work without having to reload youtube?**

To work around this problem to achieve the same goal I tried to just replace the href attribute of the home button and the logo button.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        YT test
// @match       https://www.youtube.com/*
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// @version     1.0
// @author      -
// @description 5/30/2020, 12:16:13 PM
// ==/UserScript==

document.getElementById("endpoint").href="/feed/subscriptions";
document.getElementById("endpoint").removeAttribute('class');
document.getElementById("logo").href="/feed/subscriptions";
document.getElementById("logo").removeAttribute('class');
```

However, although these commands work in the JS console, they do not take effect as greasemonkey script even if I put the `run-at` attribute to `document-end`.

**How can I make these changes automatic via Greasemonkey?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems:

1. YouTube pages have multiple elements with the same `id` in one document, which is a violation of the HTML standard, so `document.getElementById("logo")` will find the wrong one. You can use `document.querySelector('a#logo')` instead.
2. The page is built dynamically using JavaScript so the elements may appear long time after DOMContentLoaded event has occurred. You can use MutationObserver (may be resource-consuming) or setTimeout/setInterval (not precise).
3. YouTube site is a SPA (single page application) which imitates navigation by using [History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) API but userscripts are executed only on real navigation.

---

Solution:

There could be many solutions, arguably, but I suggest using a simple `click` listener in capture phase (the third parameter of addEventListener is `true`) so that you don't have to depend on the exact selector for the element, which may change unpredictably when the site code updates in the future.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        YT redir /home -> /sub
// @match       https://www.youtube.com/*
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

if (location.pathname === '/') {
  location.pathname = '/feed/subscriptions';
}
window.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const a = e.target.closest('a');
  if (a && a.href === 'https://www.youtube.com/') {
    a.pathname = '/feed/subscriptions';
    a.className = '';
  }
}, true);
```